# R Filter data based on weeks

Tags: r

I am currently filtering my data based on weeks as below. I can easily filter between last 12 weeks, how do i filter the last 20 weeks data (since it goes back to 2022)? I want to filter last 20 weeks of data from 7th week of 2023.

```
my_data
rid name    b_date
1   mac 8/12/19
2   mac 3/15/19
3   tom 5/11/21
4   tom 8/13/21
5   aj  2/3/21
6   aj  7/22/21
7   aj  7/23/22
8   mary    11/24/22
9   mary    12/25/22
10  mary    12/29/22
11  mary    1/02/23
12  mj  1/12/23
13  mj  1/29/23
14  ar  2/12/23
15  ar  2/29/23
16  ar  3/15/23 

my code:
my_data$week = isoweek(my_data$b_date)
my_data$year = year(data$b_date)

weeks_12<-my_data %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(week >= 1 & week <=12 & year == 2023) %>%
  complete(week = 1:12, fill = list(Total = 0))
```

Comment: Note that there is no Feb 29 in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# create 20-week interval
end <- ymd("2023-01-01") + weeks(7)
start <- end - weeks(20)

# filter data
df |> 
  mutate(b_date = mdy(b_date)) |> 
  filter(b_date %within% interval(start, end))
#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `b_date = mdy(b_date)`.
#> Caused by warning:
#> !  1 failed to parse.
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   rid   name  b_date    
#>   <chr> <chr> <date>    
#> 1 8     mary  2022-11-24
#> 2 9     mary  2022-12-25
#> 3 10    mary  2022-12-29
#> 4 11    mary  2023-01-02
#> 5 12    mj    2023-01-12
#> 6 13    mj    2023-01-29
#> 7 14    ar    2023-02-12
```

Data

```
# define data
df <- tribble(
  ~ rid, ~name, ~b_date,
  "1",   "mac", "8/12/19",
  "2",   "mac", "3/15/19",
  "3",   "tom", "5/11/21",
  "4",   "tom", "8/13/21",
  "5",   "aj",  "2/3/21",
  "6",   "aj",  "7/22/21",
  "7",   "aj",  "7/23/22",
  "8",   "mary",    "11/24/22",
  "9",   "mary",    "12/25/22",
  "10",  "mary",    "12/29/22",
  "11",  "mary",    "1/02/23",
  "12",  "mj",  "1/12/23",
  "13",  "mj",  "1/29/23",
  "14",  "ar",  "2/12/23",
  "15",  "ar",  "2/29/23",
  "16",  "ar",  "3/15/23"
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>